# Programming 5 inch TFT Display + Arduino Mega with Touch Shield (w/SSD1963)

Tags: arduino-mega, tft

I am newbie on Arduino and TFT Screens. But I am a semi-professional on programming and I decided to develop a device that can be controlled by Arduino via capacitive touch screen (there will be 2 buttons on the screen and while one of them will increase the current of a device, other will decrease). To do that, I've bought a complete solution (Arduino Mega + 5" TFT LCD + Arduino Shiled but without Resistive touch screen - [this one](http://www.buydisplay.com/default/display-5-inch-tft-arduino-touch-shield-ssd1963-for-mega-due)), instead of resistive touch screen, I've bought [this one](http://www.buydisplay.com/default/5-inch-capacitive-touch-panel-screen-with-controller-gsl1680f) and I've bought a separate PSU.

At the end, I have an Arduino Mega, 5 inch TFT Display, 5 inch Multi Touch Screen Panel with Controller GSL1680F (assembled to the Display) and Arduino Shield which is produced for this system. But I don't know how to communicate these three devices with each other. I know that, Arduino has built-in storage for the codes, and both TFT Display and Shield have micro-sd storage slots for placing codes. E.g. I don't know what is the aim of micro-sd storage slot on the shield.

As a result, is there any code samples / tutorials / video that I can follow to develop with this system? Thanks.

Comment: BuyDisplay have a full archive of libraries and samples for the TFT screen on the page you link to.

Comment: Hi @Majenko , Thanks for your reply. Can I use same codes on the product page for capacitive screens? Because, it is written as "8080 16-bit 5"Resistive Touch Shieid+SD Card" or can I use touch screen codes directly?)In addition what is the aim of SD Card Slot on the shield?
Because, all examples that I downloaded from product page are about Resistive Screens.

Comment: There is example code for the touch on the touch sensor page. You will need to adapt it for Arduino, or ask Google for a library. The SD card is for you to store data on, such as images to display, or sensor data that you want to record. It is the same as an SD shield.